# Is it possible to backup a phone that does not boot anymore?

Tags: sms, backup, 7.x

Phone Model :- LG Optimus - E900

OS:- Windows Phone 7.5 (installed the update on wp 7)

My phone got stuck on boot screen with LG logo and it isn't booting. I am not going for the hard reset option because of some data in it.

If i remove the battery and leave it for few hours (e.g. 24 hours) and next day it will start fine and I can see my data as well. but after 2 -3 mins it gets rebooted and same LG logo.

I have tried to fix it using the windows phone support tool as well but that isn't working as well.

I am interested to backup my data from the phone then I can try for hard reset/ factory settings

Any help in this regard would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What kind of data you want to backup? e.g. contacts, photos, music etc.?

Comment: I have everything else with me except my sms messages

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to backup a phone without booting it up. However, in this case any data that are on memory card is obviously safe and can be backup.

> If i remove the battery and leave it for few hours (e.g. 24 hours) and next day it will start fine and I can see my data as well. but after 2 -3 mins

Within this time, you can connect your phone to PC via USB and copy as much data as it allows. Repeat this process. This is not quite a solution, but it is the only option I see.